# google-api-clientでカレンダーを取得したいのですが、認証は成功しているものの、data.itemsが取得できません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

ruby 2.2.0
gem 'google-api-client', require: 'google/api_client'

以下のような実装で、実行しても、本日のカレンダーの一覧が取得できませんでした。
自分のカレンダーには確かに予定は入っております。

勿論issuerのところは正しい値を入れております。

```
class GoogleCalendarService
  def self.today_events
    cal = @client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
    @client.execute(
      api_method: cal.events.list,
      parameters: {
        calendarId: 'primary',
        orderBy: 'startTime',
        timeMin: Time.current.beginning_of_day.iso8601,
        timeMax: Time.current.end_of_day.iso8601,
        singleEvents: 'True'
      }
    ).data.items
  end

  def self.client
    @client ||= Google::APIClient.new(application_name: '').tap do |client|
      key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key('p12ファイルのパス', 'notasecret')
      client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
        token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        audience: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
        issuer: 'issuer@api-project-250641402888.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
        signing_key: key
      )
      client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
    end
  end
end
```

デバッグをする中で、

```
cal
=> Google::APIClient::API:0x3ff89b41c6ec ID:calendar:v3

hoge =     @client.execute(
  api_method: cal.events.list,
  parameters: {
    calendarId: 'primary',
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    timeMin: Time.current.beginning_of_day.iso8601,
    timeMax: Time.current.end_of_day.iso8601,
    singleEvents: 'True'
  }
)
```

hogeの返り値はGoogle::APIClient::Result:0x007ff13865fac8で、色々とデータが入っておりました。

hoge.data

```
Google::APIClient::Schema::Calendar::V3::Events:0x3ff89d345604 DATA:{"kind"=>"calendar#events", "etag"=>"\"1454212261000000\"", "summary"=>"issuer@api-project-250641402888.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "updated"=>"2016-01-31T03:51:01.000Z", "timeZone"=>"UTC", "accessRole"=>"owner", "defaultReminders"=>[], "items"=>[]}
```

hoge.data.items

```
[]
```

となってしまい、肝心なhoge.data.itemsの値は取得できませんでした。

ログを見ている限り、どこに原因があるのかがわからず、どうしたらいいのかわかりません。
どなたかアドバイスいただけないでしょうか？
宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

サービスアカウントは独立した一つのアカウントなので、サービスアカウントを作っただけではユーザーのデータにアクセスすることはできません。質問のコードでアクセスしてるのはユーザーのカレンダーではなくサービスアカウントのカレンダーです。当然何のデータもありません。

- カレンダーの設定で、アクセスさせたいカレンダーをサービスアカウントに対し共有する
- APIでそのカレンダーのIDを指定する

が必要です。

またはサービスアカウントではなくトークンを使ったアクセスに変更してください。

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います。ご指摘頂いた2点を反映させると動作致しました。サービスアカウントとトークンを使ったアカウントとの違いなど、曖昧なまま、進めてしまったことを反省してます。大変勉強になりました。宜しければ追加で質問なのですが、「APIでそのカレンダーのIDを指定する」ですが、デフォルトカレンダーは「primary」でいいという記事を複数見かけました。しかし私の環境下では「primary」ではダメでした。今回のサービスアカウントだからできなかったのか、もしくは、私のカレンダーが特殊？な事情があったためなのか、調べていたのですが、原因が特定できず・・・。もし何かご存知でしたらご教授いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 上に書いてあるとおりです。サービスアカウントを使った場合の"primary"カレンダーはサービスアカウントのカレンダーを指します。

Comment: 色々とこんがらがって理解してしまってました。今回の一連のやり取りを通じて理解できました。お付き合い有難う御座いました。